# Problem joining tables with CriteriaBuilder in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to join table using CriteriaBuilder, using metamodels.
But it seems i'm doing something wrong.

```
//this is where is get and join tables
Root<Album> mainTable = criteria.from(Album.class); 
Join<Album, Track> tracksJoin = mainTable.join(Track_.album, JoinType.INNER); //type conflict

//piece of metamodel 1
@StaticMetamodel(Album.class)
public class Album_ {
public static volatile CollectionAttribute<Album, Track> tracksList;

//piece of metamodel 2
@StaticMetamodel(Track.class)
public class Track_ {
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Track, Album> album;

//piece of DAO Album

@ManyToMany
private ArrayList<Track> tracksList;

//piece of DAO Track

private Album album;
```

Can you please explain what am I doing wrong and how to join these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in similar condition my code worked out.

```
Join<Album, Track> tracksJoin = mainTable.join(ALBUM_.tracksList, JoinType.INNER).join(Track_.album, JoinType.INNER);
```